# NFC authentication to log in PC with ACR122U USB NFC Tag Reader

Tags: authentication, nfc, raspberry-pi3

I'm kind of new with NFC and Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to create an authentication system for a PC using Pi with an ACR122U USB NFC Tag Reader. I was planning on connecting the reader to the Pi, but I was wondering if it's possible to unlock PC only after the password is entered and the NFC tag is scanned. If so how?
I also was wondering if it was possible to scan the NFC tag and take the user to an log in screen to unlock your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you try to unlock? The PC or the Pi board?

If you want to unlock a Pi with NFC tag I guess that you will have to use a PAM NFC module (see here http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Pam_nfc)

If you want to unlock a PC using a NFC with a reader connected to the PC tag see below:

The windows authentication architecture is described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169016(v=ws.10).aspx

Basically you will have to implement a "[Custom Credentials Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt158211(v=vs.85).aspx#custom_credential_providers)" and a LogonUI. I have found a GitHub repository called [Sesame](https://github.com/mclear/Sesame) that implements a complete NFC credentials provider - you might get some inspiration from there.